# Unable to connect to just one wireless network(rest all works fine)

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, windows-networking

Off-late I am stuck with an weird wireless connectivity issue in my laptop. I am able to connect to wireless networks in all other places other than one specific place.

Precisely, I am able to connect to all other places other than in my home. Previously it was working fine in my home as well. All of a sudden it stopped working. Where as wired ethernet connection at home works fine.

I did not install any new software nor driver for last few months. I have scanned for viruses as well and there is no signs of them. I went to Acer service to check my network card and its fine. I am using Windows XP and I am using broadcom 802.11g network adapter. The signal strength from the Wireless router is invariably strong in all these cases. my home connection is WPA2 secured.

This issue is just driving me nuts :( any advise or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Cheers, 
Abi

Comment: Are you able to connect to this network using another device? (laptop, phone, etc)

Comment: @Yab: All other members at home are able to connect to the network using their laptops..